# How can the typo3 backend page tree be constructed asynchronously in typo3 v9.x?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

This concerns the typo3 v9 main **page tree** in the backend view.

I have a very large page tree with about **20.000 page entities**. The query takes a long time...

In my Typo3 v9.5.5 environment, the data is **retrieved** in a **single slow query**.

How can Typo3 build the **page tree** in **several fast queries** level by level?

In the older Typo3 version (8.7.24) this also works with the method getNextTreeLevel() I think.

Comment: With the latest 9.5.20 (10.4.6) there is a fix which should take care of page tree performance problems, see release notes: https://get.typo3.org/release-notes/9.5.20 "[BUGFIX] Limit amount of data fetched by the page tree (thanks to Tymoteusz Motylewski)"

Answer (score 2):

The core team is working on it.
There are 2 patches pending:
https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62329 - this patch makes page tree less bandwidth

https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62086 - this adds asynchronous tree rendering (it's a work in progress, as needs some tuning regarding workspaces support)

Answer (score 1):

The new behaviour is like this by design in TYPO3 9.

There is a slack-channel discussing that issue: https://typo3.slack.com/messages/CK20S7EKS

And a bug-ticket on forge: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88474

Out of that there will come a patch for the core.

The only help for now is the extensions: https://github.com/bueroparallel/bp_pagetree (discussed and reviewed in the slack channel). This speed up the tree load but just loads up to a defined nesting level what results in not all pages are automatic included in the filter results. But for now (and hopefully just for a small time period) the best solution!